# kernel 3.1x and optimus support

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, nvidia

I have encountered a negative observation regarding bumblebee. Namely, using optirun the performance of the GPU seems to be an order of magnitude lower than it should be.  To be more specific:

I have a laptop with GTX660M, I have (or had, up until yesterday) a bumblebee installation with kernel 3.7.16 running (OS: openSUSE 12.3) where bumblebee was working fine. But after comparing the runtime of my code on the laptop (GTX660M) with an older card (GTX 560) in my desktop PC I have determined the runtime difference to be about 10x - very bad!

After reading up, that the linux kernel 3.12+ comes with support for optimus Graphics I thought of changing to it and did just that. That wrecked pretty much everything.
Threads like [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1357919) do not really help. (especially b/c I'm having trouble applying Arch info to opensuse)

So here's the core question:
Does GPU switching work with kernel 3.12+ and which packets are required? Furthermore, does GPGPU work then and what is the performance?

Comment: Ok. A negative info. I made the mistake to allow the system to update the kernel to 3.13. Unfortunately the 331.38 proprietary driver does not compile with it.